# unity rotate object with slider in edit virtual

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, slider, updates, virtual

How do I edit the code to make the sliders work for me?
For example, when I assign an object to my right leg, the values are loaded into the sliders, but I cannot move with them.
Lists the error:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Slider2.Update () Slider2.cs:53
thank you for advice

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEditor;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
[CustomEditor(typeof(Slider2))]
public class Slider2 : MonoBehaviour {


     [Header("Pravá noha - RightUpLeg")]
     public Transform pravanoha ;
      [Range(-360f,360f)]public float  pravanohaRX;//180.0f
      [Range(-360f,360f)]public float pravanohaRY ;  //180
      [Range(-360f,360f)]public float pravanohaRZ ;    //0.0f

        [Header("Pravé koleno - RightLeg")]
              public Transform pravekoleno ;
            [Range(-360f,360f)]public float pravekolenoRX ;   //=180.0f
            [Range(-360f,360f)]public float pravekolenoRY;   // 180.0f;
            [Range(-360f,360f)]public float pravekolenoRZ ;     //=0.0f
      
          


    // Use this for initialization
   public virtual void Start () {

}
    // Update is called once per frame
       public virtual void Update() {

 pravanohaRX= UnityEditor.TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation(pravanoha.transform).x;
pravanohaRY= UnityEditor.TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation(pravanoha.transform).y;
 pravanohaRZ= UnityEditor.TransformUtils.GetInspectorRotation(pravanoha.transform).z;

pravanoha.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(  pravanohaRX, pravanohaRY, pravanohaRZ);   

    }

}
```

Comment: Either way this won't work at all since `UnityEditor` as the name says does only exist within the Unity Editor itself. When you try to build this it would throw compiler errors since the UnityEditor namespace will be completely stripped away. You error sounds like `pravanoha` is not referenced .. note btw that it is completely inefficient and redundant to get a vector 3 times only to access the three components (x,y,z) individually .. and all that just to again use it as one vector in the end ..  simply use the vector itself ...

Comment: And then ... the `TransformUtil.GetInspectorRotation` .. it simply returns the se thing as `pravanoha.transform.localEulerAngles` ... so your method does absolutely nothing ... The values shown in the Inspector already **are** the local position and rotation ... And so you kind of overwrite whatever you do in the Inspector .. looks very strange. Have you tried to simply skip these 3 lines with `GetInspectorRotation` entirely?

Comment: Then also: remove these tags with `[CustomEditor...]` they make no sense on a `MonoBehavior` but only on a custom `Editor` class ... And instead of using `ExecuteInEditMode` and `Update` I would suggest to rather use [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) instead

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The point is that when I assign an object, the values from the rotation are read to me, but the sliders do not work